# Update table1.Col1 with Table2.Col1 when some charter in column match

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have two tables, I want to update `Col1` in `Tbl1` with `Col1` in `Tbl2`. However I want to update for rows where only some characters of Col2.Tbl1 match with Col2.Tbl2

**Table 1**

```
PK  Col1    Col2
1   NULL    abc123xyz
2   NULL    3da234oaz
3   NULL    dbc567gyz
4   NULL    agc890hyz
5   NULL    adc012jyz
```

**Table 2**

```
PK  Col1    Col2
1   001     123
2   002     234
3   003     567
4   004     890
5   005     012
```

Current query:

```
Update A
set A.Col1 = B.Col1
from Table 1 A, Table 2 B
where A.Col2 like %B.Col1%
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong column, right? In your current `UPDATE` you try to find the value of Table2.Col1 in Table1.Col2. In this case there is not match between these columns. You describe the match as follow:

> *I want to update for rows where only some characters of **Tbl1.Col2** match with **Tbl2.Col2***

So you can use one of the following solutions using `CHARINDEX` or `LIKE`:

```
UPDATE A
  SET A.Col1 = B.Col1
FROM  Table1 A, Table2 B
WHERE CHARINDEX(B.Col2, A.Col2) > 0
```

... using the following using a `INNER JOIN`:

```
UPDATE A
  SET A.Col1 = B.Col1
FROM Table1 A INNER JOIN Table2 B ON CHARINDEX(B.Col2, A.Col2) > 0
```

... or using the `LIKE` (but with the correct column):

```
UPDATE A
  SET A.Col1 = B.Col1
FROM Table1 A, Table2 B
WHERE A.Col2 LIKE '%' + B.Col2 + '%'
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8442841503faf422ca9b310befc044ed)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Update A
set
A.Col1 = B.Col1
from 
Table 1 A, Table 2 B
where 
A.Col2 like '%' + B.Col1 + '%'
```